# How to convert Matlab ode23tb function to R

Tags: r, matlab, ode

### Background

I have ordinary differential equations (ODEs) in atmospheric chemistry. I have a Matlab script, written by another guy, which can solve them. Now I have converted it into R script. However, the results are different.

In Matlab many functions are available to solve ODEs, including ode15s, ode23s, ode23t, ode23tb. My Matlab script uses ode23tb.

The deSolve package in R provides a function `ode()`, where many methods are available：

```
method = c("lsoda", "lsode", "lsodes", "lsodar", "vode", "daspk",
           "euler", "rk4", "ode23", "ode45", "radau", 
           "bdf", "bdf_d", "adams", "impAdams", "impAdams_d", "iteration")
```

However, ode23tb is not included.

### What I have tested

I tested a simple ODE from [Matlab online help](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23tb.html):

d*y*/d*t* = - 10*t*

The Matlab script:

```
tspan = [0 2];
y0 = 1;
[t,y] = ode23tb(@(t,y) -10*t, tspan, y0);
```

My R script

```
tspan = seq(0, 2, 0.2)
y0 = 1
testf <- function(t, y, p){
  with(as.list(c(y, p)), {
    dydt = -a*t
    list(dydt)
  })
}
p <- list(a = 10)
zz <- deSolve::ode(y = y0, times = tspan, func = testf, parms = p)
```

The results are different. In the R scirpt, `ode()` uses the default method 'lsoda'.

If I use ode23 method in both scripts, i.e. in the Matlab script:

```
[t,y] = ode23(@(t,y) -10*t, tspan, y0);
```

while in R script：

```
zz <- deSolve::ode(y = y0, times = tspan, func = testf, parms = p, method = 'ode23')
```

They give the same results.

However, the atmosphereic chemistry ODEs I have to solve are complicated. If I use ode23 method, the calculation is too slow in both Matlab and R. 12 hours has passed and the calculation is still going on.

### My question

How can I use Matlab ode23tb function in R? Or how can I use "lsoda" method in Matlab?

Comment: Can you clarify how the results differ? Do the solutions look completely different or are the numbers just a smidge off? (Note that `ode23tb` uses a backward differentiation formula. In R, a similar method is `bdf`.)

Comment: @Lyngbakr In the mini example, the results differ slightly. But in my atmospheric chemistry model, the results differ significantly. It is too complicated to paste the model here.

Comment: And how does the `bdf` method compare to `ode23tb`?

Comment: Also, when you use `ode23` and you get the same results using both MatLab and R, are these results the same as when using `ode23tb` in MatLab?